# Powershell pipe variables into get-user command

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to pipe a list of email addresses into a get-user command in powershell

```
$email = get-content -path "c:\temp\file.csv" get-user -indentity $email | select-object userprincipalname,department,phone,name | format-table | out-file c:\temp\file.txt
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the question? What did you try so far? What are the errors you get?

Comment: It should be easy to infer some of the ops issues. While it is a poorly worded question you should be able to see what the OP is asking

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome to SO.**

Lets see... where to start

- Email Address is not one of the value recognized for Identity
- It is spelled `-identity`
- Don't use `Format-table` for object output.
- `Department` is not one of the default values returned.
- There is no AD attribute just called `phone`
- It's `Get-Aduser` not `get-user`
- Don't know if it was just a copy paste accident but you have multiple lines as one.
- `-Identity` expects one value. Not an array of names.

Knowing that lets see if we can take a stab at what you were trying to do. Assuming that your file "c:\temp\file.csv" only contained addresses with no header (since that is how you were treating it.)

```
Get-Content c:\temp\file.csv | ForEach-Object{
    Get-ADUser -Filter "emailaddress -eq '$_'" -Properties department,OfficePhone
} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName,Department,OfficePhone,Name | Export-CSV C:\temp\outputfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

There is no error correction here so you might need to look into an `-ErrorAction` try/catch combination. I encourage you to look that up on your own.